# How to get back to normal formatting i Gmail compose message?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

If I try to quote something from e.g. Wikipedia into a Gmail mail I'm writing, it will also copy the formatting, including blue links such as [1], [2], etc. for references.

When I then try to end the quote and start writing normally again, my text is now of a smaller font, with blue color, and aligned towards the top.

My question is simply, how do I revert to the normal formatting, so I can continue typing? I have to copy/paste the quoted text (e.g. the text from Wikipedia) into e.g. gvim just to remove formatting, and then copy/paste it into Gmail. This is obviously extremely inconvenient, and also removes any formatting altogether, not just from when I want to start writing myself, after the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has formatting options available when composing an email. It is next to the Send button an underlined `A`. Clicking on it, show the options (in the blue square on the image) available to change the format of the text.

[image: IMG:]